# DbContext and Ninject

Tags: ninject, dbcontext

I just read some articles that DbContext should not be cached, so I'd like to check if this will be an concern when using it together with Ninject (or any other similar library).

Generally speaking, will Ninject use some kind of caching techniques?

```
Bind<IEntityService<Log>>().To<EntityService<Log>>();
```

where EntityService has a private dbContext reference.

```
class EntityService
{
    private DbContext _dbContext;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ninject should not use any caching if do not specify it.

If the tree of your injected objects is not cached or isn't used in some scope (singleton or per request) then each time when you resolve your reference you should have the new instance of your context.